# Return Statement and Loop

Tags: java, loops, return

I'm getting an error saying that x has not been initialized. How do I get x to return?

```
public static int sumOfOddPlace(String number){
   int x;
   for (int i = number.length()-1; i <= number.length(); i-=1){
        char c = number.charAt(i);
        x = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        x += x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change:

```
 int x;
```

to

```
int x = 0;
```

So x is also initialized if your loop is never executed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `x` is not initialized.

```
int x=0; // just initialize it
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 0;
```

`Instance fields` are always internalized to `default value`, i.e `int` will be `0`, `object` to `null` etc, where as local variables you have to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize x.

```
int x = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains because, as far as it can tell, you could get to the `return x;` before `x` is ever initialized.  This is because it doesn't know whether the loop body will ever be executed.  You and I can tell that the loop body will always be executed at least once (because `number.length()` cannot possibly be -2147483648), but the compiler doesn't try to do any calculations like that.  As far as it knows, the program could skip over the whole loop before `x` is ever set.  So you will need to initialize `x` as stated in the other answers.

Not that it matters, because your code will never get to `return x;` anyway.  It will always throw an exception.  You have told it to start `i` at 1 less than the length of the string, decrease `i` by 1 after every iteration of the loop, and keep going as long as `i` is less than the string's length, which means that it will go down to 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, ... and would keep going all the way down to -2147483648 except that it's going to get an exception first.